i am having the issue of cannot resolve symbol of embedding and flutter activity
this is my MainActivity.java  file
package com.example.alfred;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}
have tried the already present solutions in here but none of them are working open the directory and invalidate but not working
android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"  // Keep this plugin as it is needed for Flutter
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.alfred"
    compileSdk = 34  // Set the compile SDK version to 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow)
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"  // Adjust this to the correct NDK version if needed

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.alfred"
        minSdk = 19 // You can adjust this based on your app's requirements
        targetSdk = 34  // Set the target SDK version to 23
        versionCode = 1  // Your app version code
        versionName = "1.0"  // Your app version name
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with debug keys for now
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."  // Points to your Flutter project source directory
}

pubspec.yaml
name: alfred
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.4


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  
  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0


flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/labels.txt
    - assets/yolov8.tflite


  uses-material-design: true


this is Android Manifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="alfred"
        android:name="com.example.alfred.MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.alfred.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


can you provide the full error log?

on flutter run it is not showing any error but when i run the app it is build and run but again stop without any errors  but in android IDE it is only showing the following 2
errors on MainActivity.java file unresolve symbol embedding and FlutterActivity
